# Python: Sorting a list of lists

Tags: python, algorithm, list, sorting

I have a list of lists that looks something like this:

```
testList = 
[[(480.0, 349.0), (459.0, 354.0), (467.0, 343.0)] 
[(467.0, 343.0), (455.0, 344.0), (462.0, 334.0)] 
[(459.0, 354.0), (480.0, 349.0), (483.0, 366.0)] ...]
```

Each list represents triangles that I am trying to draw with a line. I have an unrelated drawing method that draws a line from first vertex to second to third and back to first vertex (thereby drawing a triangle). I also want to connect these triangles together without drawing new lines, and so I want to consecutively sequence the testList[i][0]s.

And so, I would like to reorder the vertices within the list AND `testList`, to something like this:

```
testList = 
[[(480.0, 349.0), (459.0, 354.0), (467.0, 343.0)] 
[(480.0, 349.0), (459.0, 354.0),  (483.0, 366.0)] 
[(467.0, 343.0), (455.0, 344.0), (462.0, 334.0)]...]
```

where `testList[2]` jumps up to `testList[1]`, and `testList[1][0]` and `testList[1][1]` switch.

Thanks to [Alfonso Jiménez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2406263/alfonso-jim%C3%A9nez), here is the approach I have so far:

```
for subList in testList1:
    subList.sort()
testList1.sort()
```

which works pretty well, except I still do notice in the complete testList parts like:

```
...[(215.0, 737.0), (298.0, 633.0), (317.0, 660.0)]
[(317.0, 660.0), (333.0, 599.0), (394.0, 660.0)]
[(298.0, 633.0), (317.0, 660.0), (333.0, 599.0)]
[(282.0, 75.0), (316.0, 74.0), (336.0, 71.0)]...
```

that could be rearranged to have identical testList[i][0s] but don't (notice the (317.0, 660.0) vertex not moving to position [0]. You may see the complete output [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4wnQJlEGhUhUVNkUkd6cjZLQUE/view?usp=sharing)

I am a beginner in python so any help would be incredibly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I deleted my answer, as it does not solve the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

You question is little confusing, is this what you want :

I tried recursive approach , it will chuck and reorder 3-3 items from your list :

```
testList = [[(480.0, 349.0), (459.0, 354.0), (467.0, 343.0)],
[(467.0, 343.0), (455.0, 344.0), (462.0, 334.0)],
[(459.0, 354.0), (480.0, 349.0), (483.0, 366.0)]]
def  triangles(test_line):
    updated_list=[]
    if not test_line:
        return 0
    else:

        for index,item in enumerate(test_line[:3]):
            if index==0:
                updated_list.insert(index,test_line[index])
            if index==1:


                updated_list.insert(2,test_line[index])
            if index==2:
                test_line[index][0], test_line[index][1] = test_line[index][1], test_line[index][0]

                updated_list.insert(1,test_line[index])


        print(updated_list)
        return triangles(test_line[3:])

print(triangles(testList))
```

output:

```
[[(480.0, 349.0), (459.0, 354.0), (467.0, 343.0)], [(480.0, 349.0), (459.0, 354.0), (483.0, 366.0)], [(467.0, 343.0), (455.0, 344.0), (462.0, 334.0)]]
```

> Test case with your updated long list:

```
testList = [[(480.0, 349.0), (459.0, 354.0), (467.0, 343.0)],
[(467.0, 343.0), (455.0, 344.0), (462.0, 334.0)],
[(459.0, 354.0), (480.0, 349.0), (483.0, 366.0)],
[(215.0, 737.0), (298.0, 633.0), (317.0, 660.0)],
[(317.0, 660.0), (333.0, 599.0), (394.0, 660.0)],
[(298.0, 633.0), (317.0, 660.0), (333.0, 599.0)]]
```

output:

```
[[(480.0, 349.0), (459.0, 354.0), (467.0, 343.0)], [(480.0, 349.0), (459.0, 354.0), (483.0, 366.0)], [(467.0, 343.0), (455.0, 344.0), (462.0, 334.0)]]
[[(215.0, 737.0), (298.0, 633.0), (317.0, 660.0)], [(317.0, 660.0), (298.0, 633.0), (333.0, 599.0)], [(317.0, 660.0), (333.0, 599.0), (394.0, 660.0)]]
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! Visually analyzing the testList output, I'd want (317.0, 660.0) in the fourth triangle to switch with (215.0, 737.0) to line up with the fifth triangle's (317.0, 660.0). Or the (333.0, 599.0)s in the last two triangles to move to the front of their triangles. I essentially want all 'common' vertices to reorder as the first vertices of their triangles, and order them consecutively in testList. Hope this offers some clarification. Thanks again!